# when not to use mock

Tags: unit-testing, testing, language-agnostic, mocking, bdd

I have a base class that depends on another class for some special caching. I also wrote the special caching class.

I can test it so special caching class is passed as a mock to make sure the base class works as expected or I can use a real class to make sure that the whole thing works as expected.

If I use the real class I don't have to duplicate test logic in testing the cache class since this is the only use case for it (for now).

The best idea could be to write both tests (using mock and using real class), but it might be confusing to other developers why I test it twice.

Should I use mock here or the real class?

Comment: Horses for courses... some people like to mock everything a class depends on, others like to mock only external (uncontrolled) access... or classes outside of the current module....

Answer (score 1):

Why should you mock the real class if it does the job?

My advice would be:

- test your class features in its test case, except caching,
- test caching in the cache test case

I wouldn't be confused by that, as long as the tests of your cache class are exhaustive: if caching leads to problems, caching tests should fail, and not your outer class.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the base class would depend on another class, not necessarily for caching, but for "looking after XYZ for me". The collaborating class is just acting as a repository. The class under test shouldn't know or care that the other class caches - otherwise you have coupling there that you probably don't need.

You'd then use an interface to express that. I normally call mine 'ILookAfterXYZ' - I find this pattern of naming really helps me work out what it is that my collaborating class helps me do - and mock that out.

Caching is a performance concern, rather than a behavioral one. I came to this question because it's tagged "BDD", but I wouldn't use BDD-style tests at either a unit or a system level to determine the usefulness of things like caching. Instead, write performance tests and use them to check that the caching works.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in similar situations where I had a class in production code which was backed up by a couple of unit tests. These unit tests created mock objects to pass into the production code class. That meant I was able to run the unit tests without any dependencies.

Now, I also required to use that production class as part of a BDD (using SpecFlow) test. This type of testing was more integration, in that I actually created a real object (instead of a mock) which the production class required.

So from my experience I created a mock object only for the unit tests, whilst creating a real object for my integration tests. This is very subjective though, but for me it's worked out fine.